# PrimeFaces 2, how to use ajax with a h:selectOneBooleanCheckbox?

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have a JSF / PrimeFaces 2.x UI with a check box (h:selectOneBooleanCheckbox) whose value affects other widgets.  Something like:

```
[X] checkbox1
  [____|V] combobox1
  [X] checkbox2
```

When checkbox1 is false, the selected value for combobox1 must be null, and checkbox2 must also be false.

I'd like to use ajax to set the values in the backing bean on check of checkbox1, but I don't know how to add ajax support for a h:selectOneBooleanCheckbox

Can anyone help?  Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nest `<f:ajax>` with a `listener` method in checkbox1 which does the desired job and renders the combobox1 and checkbox1.

Something like:

```xml
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{bean.checkbox1}">
    <f:ajax listener="#{bean.listener}" render="combobox1 checkbox2" />
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
<h:selectOneMenu id="combobox1" value="#{bean.combobox1}">
    <f:selectItems ... />
</h:selectOneMenu>
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkbox2" value="#{bean.checkbox2}" />
```

with

```java
public void listener() {
    if (!checkbox1) {
        combobox1 = null;
        checkbox2 = false;
    }
}
```

PrimeFaces itself has a `<p:ajax>` which offers simlilar functionality. It only uses `update` attribute whereas JSF standard `<f:ajax>` uses `render` attribute.

Comment: Thanks!  I got so used to using RichFaces' <a4j:support> in JSF 1.x that I didn't even think to look for a pure JSF2 solution.  Thanks!  BTW, looks like the method sig had to be 'public void listener(AjaxBehaviorEvent e)'

Comment: You're welcome. The event argument is not mandatory (although some IDE's will indeed jerk).

Comment: Follow-up question: Now I'm trying to add a listener to the h:selectOneMenu as well, but it doesn't appear to be working.  Do you have to do something different that listener for that?

Comment: Nothing different. Just `<f:ajax listener="#{bean.menuChangeListener}" />` ought to do. It will be invoked when the item is changed (and the menu is rendered and no validation errors have occurred).