# JavaServer Faces ajax control not updating (enabling / disabling)

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

here is a snippet from my JSF page:

```
 <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{FormXYZ_01.propertyNone0}">
        <p:ajax event="blur" render="propertyNone0" />
 </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>

<p:inputTextarea id="propertyNone0" disabled="#{FormXYZ.propertyNone0}" rows="3" styleClass="fixed400" />
```

Here is the relevant code from my backing bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="FormXYZ_01")
@SessionScoped
public class FormXYZ_01 implements Serializable {
private Boolean propertyNone0;   
public Boolean getPropertyNone0() {return propertyNone0;} 
public void setPropertyNone0(Boolean propertyNone0) {this.propertyNone0 = propertyNone0;}
```

My ultimate goal is for the textbox to disable when the selectBooleanCheckbox is checked.  I am very new to JSF and am using primefaces.

Thanks!

Comment: `<p:ajax/>` doesn't have a `render` attribute. Use `update` instead. What is the scope of your backing bean? You might get in trouble for that `propertyNone0 = false;` bit

Comment: I tried your suggested changes, still no luck.  I also added some more code to give a better idea about the bean.

Comment: I believe you should be using "change" event, not "blur"

Comment: Please don't update wrong code for fixed code (like `render` for `update`). Note that this code can be part of somebody's answer.

Comment: Looks like there's a typo in your code: `disabled="#{FormXYZ.propertyNone0}"` should be `disabled="#{FormXYZ_01.propertyNone0}"`, and your bean should be `@ViewScoped`, no need to save this data in session. By the way, `FormXYZ_01` is a legal but highly complicated name for a managed bean, I would rename it for something with a better mean for another developers (you can consider yourself *another developer* if you review the code after some time).

Comment: @ Luiggi, ok
@ root - that worked, thanks!, post an answer if you want the points

Comment: Another advice: this is not worth an ajax request, you can do it using plain vanilla JavaScript. Don't give overhead to the server for so easy tasks (later you will post a question saying *why my project is so slow* and then you would think moving on another web framework).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, good catch on the type, an issue in my post, but not my code (changed form names when posting here)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoze Agreed, but we have been instructed not to use any inline JavaScript or jQuery, but to use the JSF framework :(

Comment: @bulltorious `<p:ajax>` uses JavaScript and jQuery behind the scenes and whoever your teacher/instructor is should understand that what he/she is asking is **a bad practice** (for this case) in real world applications.

Comment: there is no render attribute for p:ajax. I tried the example given in primefaces showcase But, the ajax event is not firing.

Comment: check this may be helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179557/primefaces-2-how-to-use-ajax-with-a-hselectonebooleancheckbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that ended up working:

```
<h:form>

<p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{FormXYZ_01.propertyNone0}">
    <p:ajax event="change" update="ctrlPropertyDescLoc0" />
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>

<p:inputTextarea id="ctrlPropertyDescLoc0" disabled="#{FormXYZ_01.propertyNone0}" cols="27" rows="3" />

</h:form>
```

The take-aways are, **event** had to be "change" and **update** had to point id attribute of the target control.

Also, don't forget to wrap your controls in form tags!

```
<h:form>...</h:form>
```

Comment: most times, `event` doesn't need to be set. It'll default to the parent component's default action event

Comment: @kolossus confirmed, for my purposes "event" did not need to be set.  Thanks!